# JavaFX fullscreen - resizing elements based upon screen size

Tags: javafx-2, fullscreen

Is there any way to make fullscreen(and if possible resizing too) to instead of rearranging everything (actually what it does is to rearrange the elements like resizing but to the whole screen) to make an actual fullscreen mode? (like games that what usually do is change screen resolution), so that buttons and text grows accordingly to the size of the screen/window

Also how can I remove the message and the effect on click the "esc" key to exit the fullscreen mode?

EDIT: use this way to make resizeable

```
@Override public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception{
    final int initWidth = 720;      //initial width
    final int initHeight = 1080;    //initial height
    final Pane root = new Pane();   //necessary evil

    Pane controller = new CtrlMainMenu();   //initial view
    controller.setPrefWidth(initWidth);     //if not initialized
    controller.setPrefHeight(initHeight);   //if not initialized
    root.getChildren().add(controller);     //necessary evil

    Scale scale = new Scale(1, 1, 0, 0);
    scale.xProperty().bind(root.widthProperty().divide(initWidth));     //must match with the one in the controller
    scale.yProperty().bind(root.heightProperty().divide(initHeight));   //must match with the one in the controller
    root.getTransforms().add(scale);

    final Scene scene = new Scene(root, initWidth, initHeight);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.setResizable(true);
    stage.show();

    //add listener for the use of scene.setRoot()
    scene.rootProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Parent>(){
        @Override public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Parent> arg0, Parent oldValue, Parent newValue){
            scene.rootProperty().removeListener(this);
            scene.setRoot(root);
            ((Region)newValue).setPrefWidth(initWidth);     //make sure is a Region!
            ((Region)newValue).setPrefHeight(initHeight);   //make sure is a Region!
            root.getChildren().clear();
            root.getChildren().add(newValue);
            scene.rootProperty().addListener(this);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to resize your UI.

**Scale by Font Size**

You can scale all controls by setting `-fx-font-size` in the `.root` of your scene's style sheet.

For example, if you apply the following stylesheet to your scene, then all controls will be doubled in size (because the default font size is 13px).

.root {
     -fx-font-size: 26px;
   }

The above will work to scale controls, which is fine for things which are completely control based, but not so good for things which are graphic and shape based.

**Scale by Transform**

Apply a [Scale](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/transform/Scale.html) transform pivoted at (0,0) to your scene's root node.

```
Scale scale = new Scale(scaleFactor, scaleFactor);
scale.setPivotX(0);
scale.setPivotY(0);
scene.getRoot().getTransforms().setAll(scale);
```

To scale a game I developed which includes graphics and various shapes, I used a letter boxing technique which sized the game window to a constant aspect ratio, (similar to the letter boxing you see when you watch a 4:3 tv show on a 16:9 screen).

The SceneSizeChangeListener in the code below listens for changes to the scene size and scales the content of the scene appropriate to the available scene size.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.transform.Scale;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import org.jewelsea.games.supersnake.layout.LayoutController;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

/* Main JavaFX application class */
public class SuperSnake extends Application {
  public static void main(String[] args) { launch(args); }

  @Override public void start(final Stage stage) throws IOException {
    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(
        getClass().getResource("layout/layout.fxml"),
        ResourceBundle.getBundle("org.jewelsea.games.supersnake.layout.text")
    );
    Pane root = (Pane) loader.load();

    GameManager.instance().setLayoutController(loader.<LayoutController>getController());

    Scene scene = new Scene(new Group(root));
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();

    GameManager.instance().showMenu();

    letterbox(scene, root);
    stage.setFullScreen(true);
  }

  private void letterbox(final Scene scene, final Pane contentPane) {
    final double initWidth  = scene.getWidth();
    final double initHeight = scene.getHeight();
    final double ratio      = initWidth / initHeight;

    SceneSizeChangeListener sizeListener = new SceneSizeChangeListener(scene, ratio, initHeight, initWidth, contentPane);
    scene.widthProperty().addListener(sizeListener);
    scene.heightProperty().addListener(sizeListener);
  }

  private static class SceneSizeChangeListener implements ChangeListener<Number> {
    private final Scene scene;
    private final double ratio;
    private final double initHeight;
    private final double initWidth;
    private final Pane contentPane;

    public SceneSizeChangeListener(Scene scene, double ratio, double initHeight, double initWidth, Pane contentPane) {
      this.scene = scene;
      this.ratio = ratio;
      this.initHeight = initHeight;
      this.initWidth = initWidth;
      this.contentPane = contentPane;
    }

    @Override
    public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Number> observableValue, Number oldValue, Number newValue) {
      final double newWidth  = scene.getWidth();
      final double newHeight = scene.getHeight();

      double scaleFactor =
          newWidth / newHeight > ratio
              ? newHeight / initHeight
              : newWidth / initWidth;

      if (scaleFactor >= 1) {
        Scale scale = new Scale(scaleFactor, scaleFactor);
        scale.setPivotX(0);
        scale.setPivotY(0);
        scene.getRoot().getTransforms().setAll(scale);

        contentPane.setPrefWidth (newWidth  / scaleFactor);
        contentPane.setPrefHeight(newHeight / scaleFactor);
      } else {
        contentPane.setPrefWidth (Math.max(initWidth,  newWidth));
        contentPane.setPrefHeight(Math.max(initHeight, newHeight));
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Here is a screenshot where you can see the letterboxing and scaling taking effect.  The green grass in the middle is the main game content screen and scales up and down to fit the available screen area.  The wood texture around the outside provides a flexibly sized border which fills in the area where the black letterbox bars would normally be if you were watching a tv program at a different aspect ratio to your screen.  Note that the background in the screenshot below is blurry at the title page because I make it so, when the game starts, the blur effect is removed and the view is crisp regardless of the size.

Windowed version:

[image: letterbox]

Scaled full screen version:

[image: letterbox-full-screen]

You might think that the scaling method above might make everything go all blocky and pixelated, but it doesn't.  All font's and controls scale smoothly.  All standard drawing and graphic commands and css based styles scale smoothly as they are all vector based.  Even bitmapped images scale well because JavaFX uses fairly high quality filters when scaling the images.

One trick to get good scaling on images is to provide high resolution images, so that when the screen scales up, the JavaFX system has more raw data to work from.  For example, if the preferred window size for an app is quarter of the screen size and it contains a 64x64 icon, instead use a 128x128 icon, so that when the app is put in full screen and all elements scaled, the scaler has more raw pixel data samples to use for interpolating values.

The scaling is also fast as it is hardware accelerated.

> how can I remove the message and the effect on click the "esc" key to exit the fullscreen mode?

It's not possible to remove the full screen exit message in JavaFX 2.2, it will be possible in JavaFX 8:

[RT-15314 Allow trusted apps to disable the fullscreen overlay warning and disable the "Exit on ESC" behavior](https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-15314)

It will be nice when that is done, because then my games won't have that "look at me - I look like a beta" feel about them.

Comment: thank you very much, tried a bit of the code and seems to work, even though i did not expect that using fullscreen would be that troublesome and hard...

Comment: modified slightly the code of the listener, but changing the root width/height is not working, so when the scene grows larger than the original, the root element goes outside it, but when is smaller, doesn't cover the whole scene, can help me a bit with this issue? the code is on the following link: http://codepaste.net/cm5jzn (the scene I initialize the following way Scene s = new Scene(new Controller()), where Controller extends a Pane (can vary since i change the pane);

Comment: Sorry, your solution is a bit different than mine and I can't really debug it for you.  I did put together an [executable example of the letter boxing snippet from this post](https://gist.github.com/jewelsea/5603471) in case that might help you.  Good luck :-)

Comment: well the problem of mine is that the `Region.setPrefWidth()`,  `Region.setPrefSize()` and similars are not working, even tried setting min, max and pref at the same time to the scene value or any random value, yet the pane size didn't got affected

Comment: seems that the problem is that the root width/height cannot be modified, edited the post on a way it works (using a Pane as root between the scene and the view)

Comment: looking into this, where does the ```contentPane``` come from? is that linked to the main element that runs within the code?

Comment: I the example `contentPane` is wrapped in a `Group` which is set to be the root of the Scene.  So `contentPane` contains everything visible in the scene.

Comment: If would probably be better if the example were updated to be self contained and written to target a modern JavaFX distribution.  Perhaps I might update the answer later.

Comment: @jewelsea that makes a bit more sense. Though with grouping it just sets the position of the elements on top of each other. Is there any way set the group to not do that?

Comment: That isn’t really what a group does.  A group is just a collection of nodes without managed layout.  You can manage the layout of a group manually by setting x y and z coordinates of the nodes in it.  I’ll have to look back at the code later to see if a group is even needed in this case.  One reason for a group is that its layout bounds are calculated after applying transforms on its children,  perhaps that is why I used it here.

Comment: Note the group I use only has one element which is the content pane, not many elements as implied by your comment.

Answer (score 3):

"Also how can I remove the message and the effect on click the "esc" key to exit the fullscreen mode?"

Use this code :

```
stage.setFullScreenExitHint("");
```

It will change the string message "Press Esc to quit Fullscreen mode" into empty string so it will not show up.

Answer (score 1):

You may copy this into JavaFXApplication

```
Dimension resolution = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
double width = resolution.getWidth();
double height = resolution.getHeight(); 
double w = width/1280;  // your window width
double h = height/720;  // your window height
Scale scale = new Scale(w, h, 0, 0);
root.getTransforms().add(scale);
```