# JavaFX : What is the proper method for scaling controls on a scene/stage/window?

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8, scene, rescale

I've got a simple control that is nothing but a label and a VBox. The purpose is to inform the user of things in the program. I want to make it so that the label will scale with the scene properly. I have the methods in place to accomplish this task (I think, anyway):

```
public void reScaleX(){
    this.Message.setScaleX(( //Message is the Label Variables name.
        this.getWidth() - 40 //40 is the 20 + 20 padding given to the control.
        ) / this.Message.getBoundsInLocal().getWidth()
    );
}

public void reScaleY(){
    this.Message.setScaleY((
        this.getHeight() - 40 //40 is the 20 + 20 padding given to the control.
        ) / this.Message.getBoundsInLocal().getHeight()
    );
}
```

I add a listener to the controls Width and Height properties in the Initialize method:

```
@Override public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources){
    this.widthProperty().addListener((
        ObservableValue<? extends Number> obsV, Number oldV, Number newV
    ) -> this.reScaleX());
    this.heightProperty().addListener((
        ObservableValue<? extends Number> obsV, Number oldV, Number newV
    ) -> this.reScaleY());
}
```

But the problem is that it behaves oddly (Sometimes it will rescale, others it won't). I've also tried to add listeners to the height and width properties of the stage into which the control is being placed to make it rescale when the control resizes:

```
    this.PreviewStage.widthProperty().addListener((
        ObservableValue<? extends Number> obsV, Number oldV, Number newV
    ) ->
        this.PreviewPlaque.reScaleX()
    ); this.PreviewStage.heightProperty().addListener((
        ObservableValue<? extends Number> obsV, Number oldV, Number newV
    ) ->
        this.PreviewPlaque.reScaleY()
    );
```

But it's still not behaving correctly.

I feel like I'm doing this wrong but I don't know how to do it right. What is the proper method for rescaling a control on a form like this? Is there a better method for achieving the result for which I am looking?

Comment: See related: [javafx automatic resizing and button padding](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23229149/javafx-automatic-resizing-and-button-padding), [JavaFX fullscreen (scaling)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16606162/javafx-fullscreen) and [JavaFX correct scaling](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16680295/javafx-correct-scaling)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so my resolution to the issue was two fold:

1 (THE MOST CRITICAL): I keep forgetting to remember that in order to scale a control, the size must be relatively static: that is, DO NOT SET THE MAX WIDTH/HEIGHT TO LARGE NUMBERS. Also, do NOT allow the control to grow vertically or horizontally. That is my first (and most common and frustrating mistake).

2: Bind the scaleX and scaleY properties: This comes from my relatively recent ramp-up on property knowledge. There are many ways to accomplish the scale method but this feels the cleanest to me.

```
this.Message.scaleXProperty().bind(Bindings.createDoubleBinding(() -> {
    return (this.getWidth() - 40.0) / this.Message.getWidth();
}, this.widthProperty())
); this.Message.scaleYProperty().bind(Bindings.createDoubleBinding(() -> {
    return (this.getHeight() - 40.0) / this.Message.getHeight();
}, this.heightProperty()));
```

So in review: 1: Control to be scaled must be static in size. 2: Bind control scaleX and scaleY properties. *phew*.

Answer (score 3):

If you scale the Label, it will have a layout effect on its parent, again causing the width/heigt properties to change, triggering a fatal layout recursion.

I am not 100% sure what you want to achieve.

a) Fit the text somehow centered in the available space:

```
void testLabelPlains1(VBox box) {
    box.setFillWidth(true);

    Label first = new Label("first");
    first.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
    first.setMaxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);
    first.setMaxHeight(Double.MAX_VALUE);
    VBox.setVgrow(first, Priority.ALWAYS);

    box.getChildren().addAll(first);
}
```

b) Scale the fontsize within a resizable label:

```
void testLabelPlains2(VBox box) {
    box.setFillWidth(true);

    Label first = new Label("first");
    first.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
    first.setMaxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);
    first.setMaxHeight(Double.MAX_VALUE);
    VBox.setVgrow(first, Priority.ALWAYS);

    first.heightProperty().addListener(p -> {
        first.setFont(first.getFont().font(first.getHeight()*0.7));
    });

    box.getChildren().addAll(first);
}
```

c) Really linearily scale the text in X/Y directions

```
void testLabelPlains3(VBox box) {        
    Text first = new Text("first");

    box.heightProperty().addListener(p -> {
        first.setScaleY(0.8*box.getHeight()/20);
        first.setTranslateY(box.getHeight()/2);
    });
    box.widthProperty().addListener(p -> {
        first.setScaleX(0.8*box.getWidth()/30);
        first.setTranslateX(box.getWidth()/2);
    });

    box.getChildren().addAll(first);
}
```

... of course, the hardcoded number have to be derived from the real layout size of Text.

Comment: C. When the control changes size, I want the label to change size with it. A and B aren't close.